# Snakemake - carry resource usage across subsequent rules

Tags: python, bioinformatics, snakemake

What would be the best way in snakemake to have *resource usage permanence* for a given rule? This means that the `resources` of a given rule carries over the following rules. An example would be placing a limit to one input bam file at a time in a partition (e.g. `/dev/shm`) while it's being used by subsequent rules:

```
samples = ["sample1", "sample2", "sample3"]
motifs = ["motif_1", ... , "motif_n"]

rule all:
    input: expand("output/{sample}.{motif}.out", sample=samples, motif=motifs)

rule copy_bam_to_shm:
    input: "{sample}.bam"
    output: temporary("/dev/shm/{sample}.bam")
    resources: shm_usage = 1
    shell: "cp {input} {output}"

rule process_motif:
    input:
        bam = rules.copy_bam_to_shm.output,
        motif = "{motif}.bed"
    output: "output/{sample}.{motif}.out"
    shell: "run_bed_bam_and_beyond.py {input.bam} {input.bed} > {output}"
```

What I want is that the `shm_usage` resource constraint declared in `copy_bam_to_shm` remains in place while I'm running all the subsequent `process_motif` steps for the current sample - executing the latter rule with as many concurrent jobs as possible. Only after *sample1.bam* is done would *sample2.bam* be copied to `/dev/shm` and processed, and so forth. If that's not clear see the pseudocode below for the behavior I need:

```
# Pseudocode
for sample in samples
    copy sample.bam to /dev/shm
    for motif in motifs
        process motif (in parallel with as many motifs as possible)
    remove sample.bam from /dev/shm
done
```

Comment: I don't exactly get what you're attempting to do, but `resources` accept callables, so you could potentially save and check states in the function call as part of determining the value of the resource.  Although, I'm not sure at what point the call gets made.

Comment: That's an useful suggestion. I'm not sure how could I make a `shm_usage` callable that is tied to existence of the temporary file, but it would be something on those lines; when each temporary bam file is deleted, the `shm_usage` is vacated for the next bam file(s). To make the problem clearer, think of the DAG: `copy_bam_to_shm` branches to multiple `process_motif` sub-branches. I only want `k` main branches running at a time, where `k` is defined by the `shm_usage` resource.